# How do I set up my IIS to keep my application alive?

Tags: iis-7

I think my Webapplication gets shut down after a while.

It returns a new session if I haven't used the application in maybe 5 minutes. The session timeout is set to 720 minutes so that can't be the issue.

Is it maybe a setting in the Application Pool or something like that? I figure it is some sort of resource management. I use IIS 7.0

Comment: For security and data integrity reasons (depending on website design), I think all interactive websites should have a timeout

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We had the same issue with a web service that had to stay online in such a way that we couldn't afford the latency involved in starting it up if it went stale.

We wrote a very simple Windows Service that woke up every 3 minutes and requested a page as @Wayne suggested. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Totally forgot about windows services, that would be pefect for this... Let me know if you have it and want to send it over as I haven't created a windows service for years :)

Comment: I must admit, for our sites I actually use a minimised winform with embedded .NET browser control that read's a list of URL's from a txt file and requests each one into the browser

Comment: Sorry, napster. No can do. As much as I'd like to, the powers that be would NOT be impressed. There are plenty of samples around the 'net, so it won't be hard to put one together.

Comment: If anyone reads this and have the same needs you can find information on how to make HTTP Requests from C# here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Browsing_the_WEB_with_C_.aspx

Answer (score 59):

IIS has a feature in properties where you can stop recycle your IIS on intervals

1. Go to your "IIS Manager"
2. Select "Application Pool" the instance you want to manage.
3. Select "Advanced settings" action
4. Under "Recycling" and set "Regular Time Interval" to 0, which means the application pool does not recycle.

Comment: This is the *right* answer. The OP is long gone though.

Comment: Mine was set to 1740 minutes (29 hours) which [is the default and has been since application pools were added to IIS](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes) so I don't think this can be it - the question said it was 5 minutes.

Comment: if there is a memory leak, this might crash the system

Answer (score 39):

1. Open "IIS Manager"
2. Select "Application Pool" the instance you want to manage
3. Select "Advanced settings"
4. Under "(General)" and set "Start Mode" to "AlwaysRunning", which means the application pool keep the ASP.NET application run always

PS. If you want the ASP.NET application be loaded automatically, you can follow this:

1. Open "IIS Manager"
2. Select the application you want to manage
3. Select "Advanced settings"
4. Under "(General)" and set "Preload Enabled" to "true", which means the applicaton will be loaded automatically after its deployment.

For more information, please visit this:[Use IIS Application Initialization for keeping ASP.NET Apps alive](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/oct/02/use-iis-application-initialization-for-keeping-aspnet-apps-alive)

Comment: This doesn't work as you would expect ... we have the above problem and this is where I started.

Comment: Keep in mind - "Preload Enabled" to "true" will work only with anonymous authentication turned on.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use a script to open a connection to the website and request your page. See [Joel Oleson's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/archive/2006/08/13/697044.aspx) for more information.

You can use windows scheduler to run every x minutes.

This maybe Sharepoint specific but you can adapt to your requirements.

Update: Try this version: [WarmUpServer.zip](http://www.sharepointforum.com/Documents/Useful%20Files/WarmUpServer.zip)

Comment: the files no longer exists in that blogpost... otherwise seems to be what I was looking fore, anyone have a script that can do this for me?

Answer (score 2):

After some research on this subject, I manage to find a good reference ([Scott Forsyth's Blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes)) and it worked for me like a charm (IIS 10, but I belive it should work starting on IIS 7). Basically, you need to set application pool Idle Time-out to 0, otherwise, when you have 20 minutes without any traffic then the app pool will terminate.

On IIS, go to Application Pools --> right click on the poll you want to edit --> Advanced Settings. Under Proccess Model, change the Iddle Time-out property to 0.

[application pool advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3559.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To piggy back on this.  You can set the idle timeout via the appcmd.exe tool.  This is useful if you need to set it through an automated deployment tool.
`%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set apppool "AppPoolName" /processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Application pools do recycle, and they do restart after achieving some limits in terms of execution time or number of requests etc, that can be set on IIS.

IIS 7 actually runs in pipeline mode so its something new which we dont know yet for sure, but all you can do to make your app alive is to set a trigger from some other machine which will connect your server in every 5 or 10 or 60 minutes and try to fetch one html page.

There can be various server monitors for http as well.

Comment: well I most likely wont experience this problem once we go live because there will be a lot more usage but still it is annoying as hell... It seems so stupid to set up a ping from another server though, I refuse to believe that is the best solution :)

Comment: @napster: You're unlikely to find a better solution unless you switch to a different web server.

Comment: "but all you can do to make your app alive is to set a trigger from some other machine", why does it have to be some other machine? can't it run on the server machine?

Answer (score 0):

After failed at configuring IIS pool. I come out with this simple windows service. 
[github code](https://github.com/ChinhPLQ/Windows-Service)

It can save some minutes of you.

Answer (score 0):

"Preload Enabled" to "true" will work only with anonymous authentication turned on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Server 2008 and above, it's easy to use the built in Task Scheduler to configure a automatic request the page's URL with the default browser (in the windows server).

Guide:
https://windowsloop.com/open-webpage-on-schedule-task-scheduler/

I've been using this method to keep my site running as it has some scheduled background tasks in IIS.