# Keep alive on shared server support

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I have a followup question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781830/keep-process-running-forever) one. So, I'm using [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to run recurring jobs from a dummy webform on a shared server (somee.com). But I discovered that the IIS goes idle in x minutes, so my jobs are never executed (I mean they are only executed when the IIS is active).

So, is there any way to keep it alive? As it is a shared server I don't exactly have access to its configuration. I've read that having a service ping the website would do the trick. I've tried with [uptimerobot](https://uptimerobot.com) but didn't have any luck. It still goes to sleep...

Any ideas?

Comment: `It still goes to sleep` Normally, ping request to server every 5 minutes should keep the server alive, unless the server crashes before next ping request.

Comment: Hm... I'm testing on database insertion, inserting datetime.utcnow. I can get 2, maybe 3 insertions, and then they stop. It suggests that it's not doing what it was supposed to. I'm trying http requests from uptimerobot as well. Let's see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, neither worked. Supposedly, the ping would have worked. And I guess http would too. I don't know why but for some reason they don't... I can see that the hangfire tables are created on startup and it makes insertions just fine for about 20 minutes or so. And then it dies out...
Any ideas? I mean, any idea, as long as I can solve this annoying problem. I even thought of creating a RESTfull Web API instead, but it would mean that it would be simply waiting for a request to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to solve it. I asked for help on the HangFire forums and finally did it. Here's the link to the post: https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/keep-alive-on-shared-server/3723

TL;DR: Basically, I'd tried ping and HTTP requests with [uptimerobot](https://uptimerobot.com/) and they didn't work for me. What did was their Keyword requests. And now I have a windows scheduler simulated service. :)

Visit the [HangFire forums](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/keep-alive-on-shared-server/3723) for details.