# Prevent Asp Net Core 3 application from being stopped/unloaded/disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I have my web-application developed with .net core 3. I deploying it on hosting which is running IIS. One of the most important modules of my application is scheduled tasks that should executes during all application lifetime. The issue I faced is that application stopping after 1 or 2 hours of inactivity.

I deploy the application with the 'out-of-process' approach. To reach the goal I initializing application with this code at the `Program.cs`:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)               
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                    webBuilder.UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName);
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Also, I put these settings to the **.scproj**

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then I check my headers I can see this entry in my response headers:

```
Server: Kestrel
```

My schedules are implemented `IHostedService` and should run as background tasks.

All the above gives me the opinion that the application should run non-stop and shouldn't be disposed by IIS because it's running at the Kestrel and use IIS as a proxy server only. But in reality, it is different. Using logs I can see how after an hour or two my application stops running and does not log anymore.

Also, I don't have an access to the IIS because it is out of my permission, so I can't change it's setting. Does anybody have any idea how to get my application to run non-stop?

Comment: You might get some hints from https://blog.lextudio.com/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a

Comment: I've definitely had my frustrations with my web apps stopping background tasks in the past. One thing you could look into is using something like [Runly for your background tasks](https://www.runly.io/). It allows you to host your background jobs on the same machine as your web app but it won't stop with whims of IIS.

Full disclosure: I cofounded Runly and hope it helps people in situations like yours.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to set these IIS settings to prevent your application from automatically being recycled due to inactivity.

App Pool Settings:

1. change Start Mode to AlwaysRunning – this makes the service start up immediately, instead of waiting for a request
2. change Idle Time-out to 0 -  This will allow the service to continue to run, even though no requests are coming into it.  Otherwise, the service will shut down after the configured number of minutes due it receiving no new requests.
3. change Regular Time Interval to 0 – this will prevent the service from regularly restarting on the interval

Website settings:
On the Advanced Settings for the website, change Preload Enabled to true.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is change the `iis` settings.

Run this `powershell` script to keep alive application in `iis`. and if your server has been restarted, by this script your application run automatically

- `$AppPool` is name of your application in `Application Pools`
- `$Site` is name of your application in `Sites`

```
## IIS WebAdmin Module
Import-Module WebAdministration

$AppPoolInstance = Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\$AppPool

Write-Output "Set Site PreLoadEnabled to true"
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$Site -name applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled -value True

Write-Output "Set Recycling.periodicRestart.time  = 0"
$AppPoolInstance.Recycling.periodicRestart.time = [TimeSpan]::Parse("0");
$AppPoolInstance | Set-Item

Write-Output "Set App Pool start up mode to AlwaysRunning"
$AppPoolInstance.startMode = "alwaysrunning"

Write-Output "Disable App Pool Idle Timeout"
$AppPoolInstance.processModel.idleTimeout = [TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(0)
$AppPoolInstance | Set-Item

if ($appPoolStatus -ne "Started") {
    Write-Output "Starting App Pool"
    Start-WebAppPool $AppPool
} else {
    Write-Output "Restarting App Pool"
    Restart-WebAppPool $AppPool
}
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781357/how-do-i-set-up-my-iis-to-keep-my-application-alive) maybe helpful for you