# Advice needed with keep-alive

Tags: c++, http, iis, keep-alive

My c++ client app runs on Windows and uses WinHTTP API functions to send a request to a web service and receive response data. The web service is a FastCGI server which I also wrote in c++.

I understand the concept of keep-alive but need to pin down what I need to do to implement. I have the Keep-Alive option turned on in IIS Manager.

Does the client app need to send a header to tell the server it wants to keep the connection alive? If yes, what would it be? Is it okay to send this header on every request or do I need to keep track somehow?

Do I need to add anything to my server app? If IIS is sending the response header, does it set the timeout and max values?

Comment: This is off-topic as C++  (since IIS is certainly not standard C++).   In any event, relevant information may be available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781357/how-do-i-set-up-my-iis-to-keep-my-application-alive

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection You can get started from there.

Comment: Based on this quote, it looks like I don't have to do anything: "In HTTP 1.1, all connections are considered persistent unless declared otherwise."